# How can I get the value from an attribute using xmllint and XPath?

Tags: xml, shell, xpath

I want to get the value of name and put it in a variable using XMLLint

```
<body>
<value name="abc"></value>
</body>

echo 'cat //body/value/@name' | xmllint --shell "test.xml"

/ >  -------
 name="abc"
/ >
```

So I want to assign the value "abc" to variable $test

Answer (score 52):

You need to use [fn:string()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-string), which will return the value of its argument as `xs:string`. In case its argument is an attribute, it will therefore return the attribute's value as `xs:string`.

```
test=$(xmllint --xpath "string(//body/value/@name)" test.xml)
```

Comment: unfortunately --xpath is unsupported on a lot of installations

Comment: This only shows the value for a single element, is it possible to get multiple matches?

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 You can get multiple matches with *xmllint --xpath "//body/value/@name"*, but they will be all on the same line, unless you have version 2.9.9 or newer of the package *libmxl2-utils*.

Answer (score 8):

Try this, it's not beautiful but it works :)

I just erase lines containing `>` from stdout , cut the string to get the second part after the `=` , and delete "

```
test=$(echo 'cat //body/value/@name' | xmllint --shell "test.xml" | grep -v ">" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | tr -d \"); 
echo $test
```

Comment: Use xmllint so you don't have to use REs to parse XML. Realize you have to use REs to parse the output of xmllint.

Comment: why does it print ------- before the name attribute value? how to remove it?

Answer (score 6):

An approach with a **helper `awk` command** that supports **multiple attributes** (a streamlined version of [ego's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11684170/45375)):

```
echo 'cat //*/@name' | xmllint --shell file | awk -F\" 'NR % 2 == 0 { print $2 }'
```

The `awk` command:

- splits `xmllint`'s output lines into fields by `"` chars. (`-F\"`)

  - Note that `xmllint` normalizes quoting around attribute values to `"..."` on output, even if the input had `'...'`, so it's sufficient to split by `"`.
- only processes even-numbered lines (`NR %2 == 0`), thereby filtering out the separator lines that `cat` invariably prints.
- `print $2` then prints only the 2nd field, which is the *value* of each attribute without the enclosing `"..."`.

Assuming the following sample XML in `file`:

```
<body>
  <value name="abc"></value>
  <value name="def"></value>
</body>
```

the above yields:

```
abc
def
```

Comment: this works perfectly for me, thanks. Do you also have a nice way of assigning the values to different variables. Like VAR_1=$(echo 'cat //*/@name' | xmllint --shell file | awk -F\" 'NR % 2 == 0 { print $2 }')  ?

Comment: @dieHellste: You can `read` the output lines into variables (either in a `while` loop or, in Bash, into an array with `read -a`); if you need further guidance, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had to port my original simpler solution using --xpath to a platform lacking this feature, so had to adopt the "cat" solution too. This will handle multiple matches, tested on Ubuntu 12.04 and Solaris 11:

```
getxml() { # $1 = xml file, $2 = xpath expression
    echo "cat $2" | xmllint --shell $1 |\
    sed -n 's/[^\"]*\"\([^\"]*\)\"[^\"]*/\1/gp'
}
```

e.g. extracting instance names from a glassfish domain config:

```
$ getxml /tmp/test.xml "//server[@node-ref]/@name"
inst1
inst2
```

The sed post-processing just grabs all quoted values which was adequate for my needs (getting bits of glassfish config).

Answer (score 2):

With the goal of matching multiple lines and extract the value of their homonymous attribute and building on [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44220069/12342517) answers this worked for me and it's shorter hehe

```
xmllint --xpath "//*/@value" file.xml | awk -F\" '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: even shorter :) `xmllint --xpath "//*/@value" file.xml | cut -f2 -d\"`

Answer (score -1):

The next works for me:

```bash
xmllint --xpath '//o/@loc' file.xml | sed -n 's/[^\"]*\"\([^\"]*\)\"[^\"]*/\1\n/gp'
```

Comment: `//o/@loc`??? And why would one need this awful `sed`-command?