# Count occurrence of a tag

Tags: xml, unix

I have a few XML files and would like to count how many times the tag `<para>` occurs.

```
       <values>
          <fnstance>
            <value>00</value>
            <description>
              <para>Some text.</para>
            </description>
          </finstance>
          <finstance>
            <value>01</value>
            <description>
              <para>When this text</para>
            </description>
            <description>
              <para>Some other text for same value</para>
            </description>
          </finstance>
        </values>
```

I would like to find the tag `<para>` and count them for a each `<value>` tag. Is there a way to do this in Unix?

I tried `xml_grep 'finstance'  ../../recent/*.xml | xargs | grep -o '<para>'` which gives me the list of `<para>` elements in a give file. But I don't know how to do that for each value tag. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[xmllint](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint) is probably what you are looking for.

i.e.

```
xmllint --xpath '//value' yourfile.xml | sed s/\>\</\>\\n\</g
```

will return

```
<value>00</value>
<value>01</value>
```

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709071/linux-bash-xmllint-with-xpath) will give you some guidance on querying your xml with the `--xpath` option to `xmllint`.