# read values in an html file using shell script

Tags: shell

I need to parse value from an html content using shell script.
Ex:

```
<tr class="abc" some-value ="12344">1000</tr>
<tr class="abc" some-value ="134556">2000</tr>
```

Assume in the HTML page 50 of the same `<tr> </tr>` are there as mentioned above in the example. using shell I need to get those 50 `<tr> </tr>`. would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`xpath` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26709787/96588) - something like this should work:

```
xpath ./index.html '//tr/text()'
```