# Bash: Best way to get all string matches with grep in string

Tags: xml, bash

I'm having some troubles finding a way to get all matched values from string. I have XML string stored in a variable. From that variable I extract a string with grep. That works well for one match but since grep returns only first matched value it doesn't work exactly how I want it to.

```
XML="..."

VALUE=($(grep -oP "<tag>(.*)</tag>" <<<"${XML}" | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d "<" -f 1))
```

Is there any better/smarter way to tackle this than to find value, replace it in existing XML string so it is not a match anymore and then run that in loop until no matches are found?

Short XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlDoc>
  <docName>...</docName>
  <formats>
    <format>
      <name>a:1</name>
    </format>
    <format>
      <name>b:2</name>
    </format>
  </formats>
</xmlDoc>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex

Comment: I know this isn't ideal solution but I have pretty basic XML that doesn't have any attributes.

Comment: You should add a snippet of the expected XML. Also, you're not going to find the solution with `grep`. You need lookup groups and such, try `perl -pe 's///' $file` instead.

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709071/linux-bash-xmllint-with-xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split to multiple lines and run the grep command.

```
VALUE="$(sed 's#</tag>#</tag>\n#g' <<<"${XML}" | grep -oP "<tag>(.*)</tag>" | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d "<" -f 1)"
```

Comment: @Bayou : That's one of the reason why using _grep_ for extracting information from XML is usually a silly idea. But the OP seems to be aware of this kind of fallacy - at least I conclude this from his comment -, so for the concrete question he gives, I think the answer by etsuhisa is quite reasonable.

Comment: I've added short XML example of my document. It seems that I can't make it work with your solution (for 'name' tag). Could it be because of whitespaces?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Have you changed the `tag` part to `name` as follows? VALUE="$(sed 's#</`name`>#</`name`>\n#g' <<<"${XML}" | grep -oP "<`name`>(.*)</`name`>" | ...