# xml_grep get attribute from element

Tags: xml, linux, command-line, grep, xmllint

Is it possible (and if so, how) with xml_grep to get the value of a specific attribute from a specific element? I only seem to be able to output the information between tags.

example:

```
    <eid>
       <identity nationalnumber="13021912354" dateofbirth="20130219" gender="male">
          <name>Menten</name>
          <firstname>Kasper</firstname>
          <middlenames>Marie J</middlenames>
          <nationality>Belg</nationality>
          <placeofbirth>Sint-Truiden</placeofbirth>
          <photo>base64-string</photo>
       </identity>
    </eid>
```

output the value (in this case: 13021912354) of the 'nationalnumber'-attribute from the 'identity'-element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `xmllint` :

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//identity/@nationalnumber)' file.xml
```

For debian distro (or derivatives) `xmllint` is part of the [`libxml2-utils`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-xmllint) package and can be installed so:

`apt-get install libxml2-utils`

Comment: For me it only worked when I used the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11906002/1306012

Comment: @gilles-quenot For multiple `<eid>`s in a single file, if I want to extract `dateofbirth` for particular `nationalnumber`.....how should I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

The version of xmllint that I have installed on RHEL6.3 doesn't seem to have this magic --xpath option.    What version of xmllint provides support for this option?

Comment: xmllint: using libxml version 20800