# get xsi type of xml node

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I have an inbound XML document.  Inside the XML document there are defined XSI:TYPEs.
An example is:

```
<series xmlns="mynamespace.com">
    <node xsi-type="ED">value1</node>
    <node xsi-type="EN">value2</node>
    <node xsi-type="TC">value3</node>
</series>
```

I need to check the xsi-type against a list of eligible ones.

How can I extract the types using xpath so I can do my comparisons?
I have to do the final checks in a unix bash, so I'm using XMLLINT to try to extract them.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `//node/@xsi-type`?

Comment: yeah, no good....I get "no data"

Comment: I think it relates to the fact that you're overriding the default namespace. With your XML code I get this error `The default (no prefix) Namespace URI for XPath queries is always '' and it cannot be redefined to 'mynamespace.com'`. By changing the series node definition to something like `<series xmlns:something="mynamespace.com">` that XPath query works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value from an attribute using xmllint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611385/get-value-from-an-attribute-using-xmllint)