# How to get attribute value by another attribute with xmllint

Tags: xpath, xmllint

I've a **XML** document like this:

```
<items>
  <item id="1" name="CP_09550"/>
  <item id="2" name="CP_09551"/>
  <item id="3" name="CP_09552"/>
</items>
```

How can I get the id value with the name parameter for ex: `CP_09550` in xmllint?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611385/get-value-from-an-attribute-using-xmllint

Answer (score 3):

To fetch the value, wrap the XPath expression into a `string(...)` or `number(...)` function call:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(/items/item[@name="CP_09550"]/@id)' test.xml
```

This will return exactly `1`, so no need to further process the output in a script.

Comment: What about if I have a variable number of elements before items?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question. Better ask a new question referencing this one (if this is similar), and add example input and expected output. If you add a link here, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath extracts the wanted ID:

```
/items/item[@name='CP_09550']/@id
```

If I execute this in xmllint from the prompt I need to escape the quotes:

```
xmllint --xpath /items/item[@name=\'CP_09550\']/@id test.xml
```

Comment: Better just quote the XPath expression: `xmllint --xpath '/items/item[@name="CP_09550"]/@id' test.xml`.